# Unable to reach public EC2 instance from EC2 instances in a private subnet while setting up squid as a transparent proxy (in public subnet)

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, squid

I'm trying to setup DNS filtering using squid on an EC2 instance in a public subnet. EC2 instances from private subnets will be allowed through/blocked via the public EC2 instance.

If I SSH into a private EC2 instance and run `curl google.com`, nothing happens (google.com is in my whitelist.txt file). `/var/log/squid/access.log` shows no new entries.

If I run `ssh <private-ip-of-ec2-instance-in-public-subnet>`, I get a connection refused message from squid. I can also see a new entry in `/var/log/squid/access.log`.

I think there's a configuration error. What do I need to know in order to debug such cases? Is there a way to know where the routing is failing (from the instance or from the AWS console)? I've validated the VPC setup, routing tables, and security group permissions and don't see what's missing.

I did the setup manually, from the AWS console and via SSH in the EC2 instances.

My setup is:

1. VPC: 10.0.0.0/16

   - public-subnet: 10.0.0.0/20
   - private-subnet-1: 10.0.128.0/20
   - private-subnet-2: 10.0.144.0/20
2. Route tables:

   - public-rtb:

     - 10.0.0.0/16 -> local
     - 0.0.0.0/16 -> internet gateway
     - subnet associations: public-subnet
   - private-rtb:

     - 10.0.0.0/16 -> local
     - 0.0.0.0/16 -> ENI of public EC2 instance
     - subnet associations: private-subnet-1 and private-subnet-2
3. Security Groups:

   - public-sg:

     - All ICMP-IPV4 allowed from 10.0.0.0/16
     - SSH allowed from my local IP
     - HTTPS (TCP IPV4, port 443) allowed from 10.0.0.0/16
     - HTTP (TCP IPV4, port 80) allowed from 10.0.0.0/16
   - private-sg:

     - SSH allowed from 10.0.0.0/16
     - All traffic allowed from itself
4. EC2:

   - EC2 instance in the public subnet with squid installed and configured
   - 2 private instances in the private subnet

Squid setup:

1. Setup an OpenSSL certificate in the public EC2 instance

```
mkdir /etc/squid/ssl
cd /etc/squid/ssl
openssl genrsa -out squid.key 4096
openssl req -new -key squid.key -out squid.csr -subj "/C=XX/ST=XX/L=squid/O=squid/CN=squid"
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in squid.csr -signkey squid.key -out squid.crt
cat squid.key squid.crt >> squid.pem
```

2. Setup the squid config

```
visible_hostname squid 
cache deny all 

# Log format and rotation 
logformat squid %ts.%03tu %6tr %>a %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru %ssl::>sni %Sh/%<a %mt 
logfile_rotate 10 
debug_options rotate=10 

# Handle HTTP requests 
http_port 3128 
http_port 3129 intercept 

# Handle HTTPS requests 
https_port 3130 cert=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.pem ssl-bump intercept 
acl SSL_port port 443 
http_access allow SSL_port 
acl step1 at_step SslBump1 
acl step2 at_step SslBump2 
acl step3 at_step SslBump3 
ssl_bump peek step1 all 

# Deny requests to proxy instance metadata 
acl instance_metadata dst 169.254.169.254 
http_access deny instance_metadata 

# Filter HTTP requests based on the whitelist 
acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid/whitelist.txt" 
http_access allow allowed_http_sites 

# Filter HTTPS requests based on the whitelist 
acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_name "/etc/squid/whitelist.txt" 
ssl_bump peek step2 allowed_https_sites 
ssl_bump splice step3 allowed_https_sites 
ssl_bump terminate step2 all 

http_access deny all
```

3. Changed the port

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3130
```

Comment: Do you have NAT Gateway/NAT instance set up ? Also do you have that entry in your route table

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon a NAT gateway would defeat the purpose of having squid as a proxy, right? Traffic from the private subnets would go to the NAT gateway and bypass squid?

My route table sends private subnet traffic to the ENI of the public EC2 instance. Maybe I need to set some NAT configuration via iptables (in addition to the prerouting listed in the last code block)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that in your config file, you've got `http_access deny all` but no ACLs allowing traffic from any network

for example (from the `squid.conf` template):

```
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all
```

for simplicity, you can add these 2 lines at the beginning of the config file (must be before `http_access deny all`):

```
acl acl_name src your_public_ip
http_access allow acl_name
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Shereen. I did fix this a while ago with the root cause being that the EC2 instance's source/dest check was not set as False. I did change the config file as well while troubleshooting. I'll post the solution as an answer when I login to work tomorrow.